# ReactJS - Disable specific button

Tags: reactjs, button, react-hooks

I have a loop (map) that construct many buttons with different ids.

I'm trying to disable a button according your id through click yourself, but it doesn't work.
I have the following code:

```
function handleFlipCard() {
  const cardPosition = cardCompare[0].cardPosition 

  document.getElementById(`b${cardPosition}`).style.cursor = "default" // it does works
  document.getElementById(`b${cardPosition}`).border.style = "3px solid white" //it does works

  document.getElementById(`b${cardPosition}`).disabled = true //WHY IT DOESN'T WORKS?
}

{cardsScreen.map((cardScreen, index) => (
  <button className="btCard" onClick={handleFlipCard} disabled={buttonDisable} id={`b${index}`}>
))}
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is a really bad practice to control component behavior with JavaScript Vanilla.

The best in this case is to create a state to store the ID`s that are disabled and to populate the state based on the click.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Button() {
    const [disabledButtons, setDisabledButtons] = useState([]);

    const handleFlipCard = (id) => {
        // do wherever you want
        setDisabledButtons(prevState => [...prevState, id]);
    }

    {cardsScreen.map((cardScreen, index) => {
        const id = `b${index}`;
        return (
            <button 
                className="btCard" 
                onClick={handleFlipCard(id)} 
                disabled={disabledButtons.includes(id)} 
                id={id}
              >
                Content
            </button>
        )
    })}
}
```